# Hyper V Remote Manage Windows 2012 Server R2 from Windows 10 otuside domain not working

Tags: hyper-v, remote-management

It appears to be nearly impossible to remote manage a hyper v windows 2012 server r2 using windows 10 hyper v management tools.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts

As stated in this readme by microsoft in the link above you cannot remotely connect to another hyper v host on windows 2012 server r2 as another user. But i cannot connect to the server as the same user either?

-------------SERVER Configuration-----------

Server i have user "test1" and user is part of the Hyper V Administrator group on the server.

On server i have granted the hostname of the client machine to trusteddomains.

---

-------------CLIENT Configuration-----------

Windows 10 client i am logged on with user test1 and test1 is an administrator of this computer.

---

Both server and client user "test1" has the same password.

Trying to connect via the hyper v manager to SERVER from windows 10 client will give me error message:

> You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the Administrator of the authorization policy for the computer "SERVER"

Running windows 8 client with user "test1" connecting via hyper v manager instantly works to SERVER.

What is wrong with windows 10 Hyper V Tools? Or am i mistaken that adding the same user accounts on both computers does not count as the same user?

Shouldn't Microsofts docs simply say as long as you are not part of a domain you CANNOT remote administer anything except windows 2016 server if you have windows 10?

Am i mistaken here or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No resolution, ended up putting up a domain in order to control the hyper v park over windows 10.